# IndexOf a ComboBox just will not work for me

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, combobox, enumeration, indexof

VB2010. I am trying to populate a ComboBox with the contents of an Enumeration of units. I have managed to do this with a Dictionary. Something like

```
Dim dUnits As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Dim da As String

For Each enumValue As eUnits In System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(eUnits))
   da = ConvertEnumToCommonName 'gets unique name for an enumeration
   dUnits.Add(da, enumValue)
Next

cbo.DisplayMember = "Key"   'display the the common name
cbo.ValueMember = "Value"   'use the enumeration as the value
cbo.DataSource = New BindingSource(dUnits, Nothing)
```

When I load up my form that works well. Now the user can choose to select a default unit to display. So then I try

```
Dim defUnits As eUnits = eUnits.Feet
Dim idx As Integer = cbo.Items.IndexOf(defUnits) 'doesnt work, returns a -1
cbo.SelectedIndex = idx
```

I have been doing some research for some time and am fairly sure that this has to do with the `ComboBox` storing Values as a string and in reality I'm searching for an enumeration which is an integer. Don't know if I have that right or not. Anyway, I just cant seem to get the default item selected. Is there another approach I can try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have a collection of integers and you're searching for the enum value. For that, try one of the following:

1. Store the enum value in the dictionary instead of a string:

   ```
   Dim dUnits As New Dictionary(Of String, eUnits)
   ```
2. Keep the integers in the Dictionary but use the integer value of the enum when searching the ComboBox:

   ```
   Dim idx As Integer = cbo.Items.IndexOf(CInt(defUnits))
   ```

---

But **this is not going to work yet**. You are data-bound to a `Dictionary`, which means the items in `cbo.Items` are not of the enum type, but of *the type of the elements in the Dictionary* (`KeyValuePair(Of String, eUnits)` assuming #1 above).

The easiest solution is just to set the `SelectedValue` property of the combo box instead of the `SelectedIndex`. Assuming you used option #1 above, this would be:

```
cbo.SelectedValue = defUnits
```

If you used option #2 instead, you'll have to convert this to an integer first:

```
cbo.SelectedValue = CInt(defUnits)
```

Comment: Well I'm not storing a string for value Dictionary(Of String, Integer) and enumValue is an integer. By changing the dictionary to Dictionary(Of String, eUnits) I'm not really changing anything since the enum is still an integer correct?

Comment: Sorry I was maybe not 100% clear. It's the integer that's throwing you off. The underlying type of the enum is an integer, yes, but in reality, the enum and the integer are different types (in reality an enum is the underlying value plus type information). So the combo box is looking for an enum value of type `eUnits` and when all it finds are integers, it gives up.

Comment: gotcha. i made the recommended tweaks and its still not selecting the default option. I wonder if my last resort is to cycle through the combobox and try to do a manual match. ok for small lists but a performance hot for big lists.

Comment: btw I tried with both CInt(defUnits) and just defUnits and no joy. Im kind of stumped but at least i know why it doesnt work. Could i change to a ListOf or a DataTable? Dont know if that will help or not.

Comment: @sinDizzy Hang on a minute, I just re-read the question and realized one more thing that's happening -- you can check what type `cbo.Items(0)` is at runtime. It's probably a `KeyValuePair`... let me rework my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help. i have tried every combination of .indexOf and .SelectedValue. Although I dont think I tried with a Dictionary(Of String, eUnits). Let me give that a shot tomorrow.

Comment: Success!!!! Your last addition was the one that worked. What do I do now? Edit my original post with the solution or just add a comment to this thread?

Comment: @sinDizzy Glad this worked :) You've already accepted this answer (the green checkmark) so you're done. Hopefully your question will help other people too.